Where to get google-services.json file
How to get the google-services.json file. I am making a single-page free app without any Firebase server. Do I still need to make google-services.json from Firebase?
The whole process of publishing an app is more confusing than developing the app itself.
Tried the service accounts JSON file from the Google Cloud console but it didn't work.

Welcome to SO. You can't make a firebase app without using a Firebase product - that includes configuring your app and setting it up in the Firebase console. Firebase is an online first database so it requires server access. Go through the Getting Started guide for the product you want to use as that will get you going.

If you are developing an Android app, you will also need a developer account: https://developer.android.com/distribute/console

It's not needed if your app doesn't need firebase. google-service.json file comes from the android project setting on firebase.

If I dont add the file I get the following error when making a production build with expo.
Waiting for build to complete. You can press Ctrl+C to exit.
✖ Build failed
Android build failed:
"google-services.json" is missing, make sure that the file exists. Remember that EAS Build only uploads the files tracked by git. Use EAS secrets to provide EAS Build with the file.
Learn more

it's because you have installed firebase in your project. You have to add that file. You can have it from firebase project->project settings->your android app.


I am making a single-page free app without any Firebase server. Do I still need to make google-services.json from Firebase?

If you don't want to interact with Firebase in any way, then there is no need to add the google-services.json file to your project.

How to get the google-services.json file?

If you however need to interact with Firebase, then you should create a new Firebase project inside the Firebase console, download the google-services.json file, and add it to your project.
If you also need to publish your app, and you're using for example Firebase Authentication, please note that you need some keys in order to make it work:

Firebase UI authentication with google fails with message (code:10 message:10)


Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
